# How to integrate JasperReports with Struts-Spring web application?

Tags: java, spring, jasper-reports, struts

I have designed *.jrxml* (*JasperReport*) using *Jaspersoft Studio* (*Eclipse plug-in*).
 
Now, I want to integrate this report to my previous *Struts-Spring* web application so that through the jsp page, client would be able to open the report & save into pdf format.
 
Now what & how integration should be done?
 
Which changes should I do in my *web.xml*, *struts.xml*, *application.xml* & *jsp pages*?

Comment: https://github.com/coding-idiot/jasper-java-examples

Comment: few struts2 jasper samples can be found here https://github.com/coding-idiot/jasper-java-examples